# NullReference at httpContext.HttpContext.User.Identity, can it be countered?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, httpcontext

I try to create a windowsIdentity for authentication, and for this, i try to get the current user's identity, but i get null reference exception on the returned User of the context.

It's running ASP .NET core 2.2.1, i tried to pinpoint the problem, but doesn't get closer without debugging.

```
WindowsIdentity IdentityProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext){
return (WindowsIdentity)httpContext.HttpContext.User.Identity;
}
```

It should be the active user's identity, but instead its null.

Comment: (Debugging is not available for this service unfortunately, the dev environment doesn't have this problem)

Comment: There’s no `WindowsIdentity` in .NET Core. And I don’t believe the identities of the ASP.NET Core user principal can be something other than ClaimsIdentity by default.

Comment: Yes, it is ClaimsIdentity, and it's identity has nulls for the properties.